# Firefox3.5 addon for Regular Expression Search?

Tags: firefox, regex, browser-addons

I've tried to look for an add-on with Firefox 3.5 which enables me to look up web page content against regex. I didn't find anything that helps, how about you?

The version that I am using is Firefox 3.5. For compatibility reasons I am afraid I have to stick with this main version without upgrading to upper versions :(

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closest match which is registered with mozilla addons is this one https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9531/

Comment: Thanks for that, I really don't know how could you find it :) But it seems not "searching against the web content directly", I've got to firstly copy some of the text into the content panel then execute from there...

Comment: @Michael Mao so did this answer your question or are you still looking?  I noticed you didn't accept an answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

[/Find Bar/](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/99836/) is a find bar replacement with regex search capabilities. 
Currently it claims to work with Firefox 2.0b1 - 3.6.*.

[XUL/Migemo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5239/) also seems to have regex search functionality.